# How to connect to EC2 in private VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I create a VPC, and try to connect to a EC2 by connecting to AWS Ubuntu.

But when I go to the page of connecting, it showed me this

```
The instance does not have a public IPv4 address
To connect using the EC2 Instance Connect browser-based client, the instance must have a public IPv4 address.
```

**What I've tried**

In EC2 Panel > Action > Networks > Manage IP Address > Ipv4 Addresses > Assign New IP Address(only available for priate IP Address, but I couldn't do anything in section of pubilc IP Address)

Comment: Did you allocate an elastic IP?

Comment: What do you mean by "Private VPC"? Do you actually mean a "Private Subnet"? Or are you referring to a VPC that does not have an Internet Gateway?

Comment: Yes, I mean private VPC

Comment: Did my solution answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the EC2 dashboard, on the left panel, open `Network & Security -> Elastic IPs`

Allocate an elastic IP, and click `Actions` dropdown. Click `Associate Elastic IP address`.

You can connect the elastic IP to your instance or Network interfaces of the instance.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the AWS link instruction.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-associate-static-public-ip/

Answer (score 0):

First, do you mean Private Subnet?
Also ensure port 22 is open from correct ip. Private EC2 can't be accessed from public internet.
To connect with EC2 in private subnet you need a bastion host & NAT gateway attached.
Refer this [link](https://digitalcloud.training/ssh-into-ec2-in-private-subnet/) for more info.